# How to tell cucumber go to some page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning to test with cucumber + capybara.

In one video tutorial I found that something like this should work:

```
...
When I go to the homepage
Then /do stuff/
```

I'm trying to do that but cucumber treats the word "homepage" as a part of regex.

So it gives me the suggestion to create a statement like so

```
When /^I go to homepage$/ do
   #tasks
end
```

Tried "index page", "items page" (name of existing controller), "root path" - same thing. Cucumber doesn't actually go there - just asks to create a handler.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a gem such as [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) you could do something like so

In you test:

```
When I go to the homepage
```

In your step:

```
When /^I go to the homepage$/ do
 visit root_path
end
```

Or to generalize:

```
When /^I go to the "(.*)"/ do |place|
 visit "/#{place}"
end
```

where your step would pass in the location (url) where you would want to go.

For more info on `visit` method checkout [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#navigating)

Answer (score 1):

I actually went to the GitHUb Wiki for Cucumber, and found answer there.
It's as simple as `visit "/"` in steps definitions.